# Json not work in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, scripting

I wanna to use this json to my sites shopping cart .it works well in visual studio 2017 but in visual studio 2013 it does not work. please help me to solve it.

```js
function AddtoCart() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/Home/AddToCart',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'Json',
    data: {
      ProductID: @Model.product.id,
      count: My_Count.value
    },
    error: function(err) {
      alert(err.status);
    }
  }).done(function(data) {
    $('#Total_Cost').text(data.Total_Price)
    var Text = "";
    $.each(data.lst_ShoppingCart, function(index, val) {
      Text += "<tr><td class='col-sm-8 col-md-6' ><span id='Product_Name'>" + val.Product_Name + "</span></td ><td class='col-sm-1 col-md-1' style='text-align: center'><input type='text' class='form-control' id='exampleInputEmail1' value='" + val.Count + "'></td><td class='col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center'><span id='Product_Cost'>" + val.Single_Price + "</span></td><td class='col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center'><span id='Total_ProCost'>" + val.Price + "</span></td><td class='col-sm-1 col-md-1'><button type='button' onclick='RemoveCart(" + val.ID + ")' class='btn btn-danger'>Remove</button></td></tr>";
    })
    $('#Pro_Cart').html(Text);
  });
}
```

also I know that this part of code not working:

```js
url: '/Home/AddToCart',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'Json',
  data: {
    ProductID: @Model.product.id,
    count: My_Count.value
  },
```

Comment: This is important how you open it in Visual 2013 just by creating new or opening it, or VS 2013 may use older version of JQuery,Framework and etc... which means created proj in VS 2017 is not back-ward compatible with older version...

Comment: but I checked all these package update in nuget packet manager .all updated . .the project in vs 2013 exactly like the project in vs 2017.